# is there a way to automate keyboard presses and send back other key strokes in bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash

Good evening everybody,

I'm brand new to writing bash scripts and Linux OS.  In windows, I use to use autohotkey scripts to automate keystrokes and send back other keyboard strokes into a program.  I know that bash has expect, send, keydown, keyup commands.   How would I best write a script where I push these sets of keys but can then send other keystrokes to my program in bash?  thanks for your help.

Comment: AFIK, there is no builtin command for this task in bash, at lest not in version 4.4 which I am using. Maybe they added something in this way later on. There are tools which you can install to feed input to other programs. A popular one is [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), which is based on the programming language Tcl. Since Tcl is easy to learn (although a bit outdated), I suggest to give this a try.

Comment: Thanks.  I probably have it wrong.  Would xdotool be able to do this?  I'm brand new to the linux operating system.

Comment: xdotool works for automation on the X Window System level, and if this is what you want to do, you can use it. I have never used it and I don't know to what extend it can also process and react on the output of the applications. My impression was that you want to "remote control" another program, i.e. providing automatic input on reaction of its output. Maybe you should edit your question and give some insight in what exactly you want to do.